# On number of solutions by simplex and number of solutions in total in a linear optimization problem?

Tags: linear-programming, global-optimization

This is more of a clarification query.

Mizuno http://www2.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/012opti/files/talk_mizuno1.pdf says if we give a linear optimization problem
$$\max c'x$$
$$Ax\leq b$$
where $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ is totally unimodular then the simplex method has only $O(nm\|b\|_1)\log(m\|b\|_1)$ solutions.

> 1. Does it mean an unimodular constraint LP cannot have exponential number of solutions or is it simply that a simplex solution can only find a small fraction of them?
> 2. Is there any general bound on number of solutions?

Comment: That bound is about the number of iterations of the simplex method, not the number of solutions.

Comment: Expanding on Mahdi ' s comment, Basic feasible solutions are not necessarily optimal, whereas by "solution", you apparently mean optimal solution.

Comment: @Mahdi they say the bound is number of basic feasible solutions which in turn bounds number of iterations and that is the indirect connection as I understand to number of iterations. In any case the query remains.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Yes. That highlights my point better. Can we have exponentially many optimal solutions while Simplex produces only poly number of them in Totally Unimodular case or does Totally Unimodular case always have only polynomial number of optimal solutions? I think it is likely the former.

Comment: @Turbo It is more accurate to say the bound is about the number of distinct BFSs
generated by the simplex method which is a subset of BFSs. On the other hand, note that it is possible to have infinitely many optimal solutions, So by "solution" you mean extreme optimal solution.

Comment: @Mahdi yes optimal solutions which is what minimization should do and we expect. There are exponentially many correct?

Comment: By "extreme optimal solution", I mean optimal solutions which are a vertex of the polyhedron $Ax\le b$. If an LP has two optimal solutions $x_1,x_2$ then every point in the convex hull of $x_1,x_2$ is also an optimal solution.

Comment: @Mahdi I think there is a confusion here. I meant exponentially many corner point solutions.